# Git: Pure merges of Feature branches

Tags: git, merge

I have the following case:

```
mainline ---x----NNN-----x---------
            |            |
            |   feature  yyyyyyyy
release     x ----------------------x
```

I like to have the feature branch in the release branch. But I like to have it "pure", meaning I do not like to have the commits NNN in the release yet.

One option would be to create a new branch and do a rebase --onto

```
git branch feature_for_release feature
git rebase --onto release mainline feature_for_release
git checkout release
git merge feature_for_release
git branch -d feature_for_release
```

But I do not like to create new branches just for a merge and the method is pretty lengthy.

Is there a solution like this?

```
git checkout release
git merge feature --without mainline
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [cherry-pick](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry-pick.html) a series of commits from your feature branch onto your release branch.

Comment: But with this "git branch --contains feature" does not work, right?

Comment: No, it won't. You cannot merge/rebase/cherry-pick some but not all of a branch's history and still have `--contains` work. It's impossible, by design. "Contains" works by commit IDs, and by moving commits around, you're changing their commit IDs.

Comment: @schoetbi I think the method in your post also make `git branch --contains feature` not work.

Comment: @pktangyue It would work for a rebase as it would update the branch pointer as well, but then the *old* branch wouldn't "contain" the feature branch anymore. The branch pointer can only point to one place at a time. If you want the same series of commits to be contained by multiple diverging branches, the only solution is merging.

Comment: @meagar but he new a branch first, then delete it after `rebase`

Comment: @pktangyue. You are probably right, since I would need different commits with new hashes. Is it true that in git there is no thing to track the origin from a cherry-pick or a rebase operation automatically?

Comment: @schoetbi or you can rebase `feature` branch first, then merge it in your `release`

Comment: The solution what I use now is first do a rebase onto and then do a merge. This leads then to several branches for the same feature applicaple to several targets. Maybe I use the folder sorting for this OnMainline/Ticket123, OnRelease1/Ticket123